# Issues with dynamic arrays, pointers and copy-constructors

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor, dynamic-arrays, assignment-operator

I'm having a lot of issues with creating a dynamic array containing objects.

As I've understood it, because my array is handling objects, the class stored in the array must have a copy constructor or an assignment operator so that all will be copied properly.

I've successfully created this program with a normal array of defined size. Now I have a lot of problems creating the same program with a dynamic array.

Class 1 The objects to be stored:

```cpp
class objToBeStored{
private:
    string dataToBeStored;
    int sizeOfArray;
    string *storedArray;
    
public:
    objToBeStored(); //empty constructor
    objToBeStored& operator =(const objToBeStored& o); // assignment operator
    ~objToBeStored(); //destructor (no code inside);
    bool getData(istream &stream);
    //.....other methods to do stuff
};
    
objToBeStored::objToBeStored(){
    //empty
}

objToBeStored& objToBeStored::operator=(const objToBeStored& o){
    if(this != o){
        dataToBeStored = o.dataToBeStored;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
            storedArray[i] = o.storedArray[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

void objToBeStored::getData(istream &stream){
    stream >> dataToBeStored >> sizeOfArray;
    storedArray = new string[sizeOfArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        stream >> storedArray[i];
    }
    return !stream.eof();
}

//.....other methods to do stuff
```

Class 2 contains the dynamic array that stores the above objects. Everything is working,except how I declared my dynamic array and the functions handling it. Therefore I will write this code below:

```cpp
class storageArrayClass{    
private:
    storageArrayClass *store;
    storageArrayClass *storptr;
    int numberOfstored;
    
public:
    storageArrayClass(); //empty constructor
    ~storageArrayClass();
    void addElm(objToBeStored & o);
    //other functions to do stuff    
};
    
storageArrayClass::storageArrayClass(){ //constructor
    numberOfstored = 0;
}

storageArrayClass::~storageArrayClass(){
}
    
void storageArrayClass(istream &stream) {
    
    objToBeStored o;
    o.getData(stream);
    
    if(numberOfstored == 0){ //check it this is the first element
        store = new objToBeStored[1];   //create a new array with length 1
        store[(numberOfstored] = o; //store object
    }else{
        objToBeStored tmpStore = new objToBeStored[(numberOfstored+1];  //create a temp. array with 1 more position
        for(int i=0; i < numberOfstored; i++){
            tmpStore[i] = store[i]; //copy original array to the temp. array
            storptr = &tmpStore[i]; // increment a point
        }
        
        storptr++; //increment pointer to last position
        *storptr = o; //store object in last position
        
        delete[] store; //delete the original array
        store = new objToBeStored[(numberOfstored+1]; //create a new original array
        store = tmpStore;//copy temp. array
    }
}
```

I manage to add 3 objects to my dynamic array before I get the following error:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 5.059 s

Please help. I've read countless threads here, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Replace `string *storedArray;` by `std::unique_ptr<string[]>` and many of your remaining errors will be caught by the compiler.

Comment: in your copy constructor, if `sizeOfArray` and `o.sizeOfArray` are not the same, you have a big problem

Comment: Why don't you just use a `std::vector` of *objects* - *not* pointers to objects?

Comment: I have to do it with dynamic arrays

Comment: sizeOfArray and o.sizeOfArray should be the same

Comment: @NoviceJava Why did you leave out writing the destructor for `objToBeStored`?  Why did you leave out writing a destructor for `storageArrayClass`?  With what you've shown us, the program could easily go haywire with a simple 3 line `main` program, all due to the class(es) not having correct copy-semantics.  Any program run against stubbed out or missing destructors is going to cause issues.  The first thing you should have made sure is to see if the objects can be copied, and then worry about adding entries later on.

Comment: Also, what is the actual reason why you cannot use `std::vector`?   If you know Java, then the rough equivalent of what you would do in Java to accomplish this is to use (I guess) `ArrayList`.  In Java, you don't waste time trying to implement dynamic arrays by hand, and the same thing should go for C++, unless you have intermediate to advanced knowledge in C++ (and even then, use `std::vector`).

Comment: If this was in Java I would use a map or binary tree and not having to worry about memory cleanup :)

Comment: For C++ use `std::map`.

Comment: ok so I will start by looking into the destructor and see if that helps, thank you for your advice.

Comment: it has to be dynamic arrays else I would just use a vector

Comment: A vector *is* a dynamic array.  All of the work you're doing now is *exactly* what vector does, except correctly, efficiently, and safely.  A vector isn't a mystery class that does magic outside of the C++ language.  It wraps all of what you're attempting to do with `new[]` and `delete[]` and does so correctly.

Comment: First thing first, you never increase `numberOfstored`.

Comment: thank you for all your comments, this question is solved.